# Debug Assertion Failure : expression : string subcript out of range

Tags: c++, string

I'm using VS 2013 Ultimate
Here my code that program state that it have problem

```
string word_filter(string word){
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        cout << word[i] << " ";
    string result;
    char tmp;
    char ch1 = word[0], ch2 = word[1], ch3 = word[3];
    if (alphabetic_order(ch1) == 37 && alphabetic_order(ch2) == 37)
        return " ";
    int i = 0;
    while (i < word.length()){
        if (alphabetic_order(word[i]) != 37) {
            tmp = word[i];
            result += tmp;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Please help me !

Comment: Welcome to SO : ). What is the problem stated? What is the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry then this may be the problem

ch1 = word[0], ch2 = word[1], ch3 = word[3];

check for length or put atleast 4 character array in Word you are passing else these line of code will fail

Comment: actually it is a function in C++.

Comment: @smilepleeeaz: Althought it is not said correctly, his answer seems correct, why did you downvoted?

Comment: but since he's changed his answer, I should take my downvote back.

Comment: yeah, i got it, thanks a lot. So i wanna check whether the first character is in 'a' -> 'z', '0' -> '9' or not. How can i do

Comment: int isalpha ( ch1 ) this will return true if ch1 is alphabet means a to z or A and Z

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you are passing a `word` that has fewer than four characters, and do not check for the minimal length:

```
char ch1 = word[0], ch2 = word[1], ch3 = word[3];
```

The code above requires the word of at least four characters, but there is no check for `word.length() > 3` anywhere in your code.

Comment: But i want to check whether the first character is in 'a' -> 'z', '0' -> '9' or not. How can i do ?